# CREATE PROCEDURE in NetBeans IDE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, netbeans, procedure

I just wanted to add a simple procedure in Account table in Bank_Admin Schema.

The procedure adds some amount of money to the existing balance an account holder has. I guess, by reading the Sql command, you will figure it out.

But I am getting this error:

> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42X01] Syntax error:
>   Encountered "BEGIN" at line 2, column 1.
>
> Line 2, column 1
>   Execution finished after 0.036 s, 1 error occurred

.Please help me with this code...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deposit_in_bank (IN bank_account int, IN deposit_amount int)
BEGIN 
UPDATE BANK_ADMIN.ACCOUNT SET balance = balance + deposit_amount WHERE account_no = bank_account
END
```

Comment: You need an AS before your BEGIN.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that defining a SQL stored procedure in NetBeans is the same as doing so directly as a SQL statement. If so...

I don't think your `IN` keywords are valid, all parameters are presumed to be input parameters unless specified as an output parameter.

As [scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon) points out, you also need `AS` before your `BEGIN`.

I don't think you actually need your `BEGIN` and `END` at all either. Or the brackets around your parameters.

And I don't think you're writing your parameter variables correctly (they should be prefixed with `@`, so the following should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deposit_in_bank 
    @bank_account INT,
    @deposit_amount INT
AS
    UPDATE BANK_ADMIN.ACCOUNT 
    SET balance = balance + @deposit_amount 
    WHERE account_no = @bank_account
```